# Python How to edit a Tkinter label from within a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I need to change a Tkinter label from inside a function but it isn't passing through correctly because I get the error

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'config'

My code is

```
from Bio.Seq import Seq
from Bio.Alphabet import IUPAC
from Bio import SeqIO
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk, filedialog
import os

def select_file(fileLabel):
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=".")
    name, extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
    extension=''.join(extension.split('.', 1))
    for seq_record in SeqIO.parse(filename, extension):
        sequence = seq_record.seq
    fileBase=os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(filename))
    fileLabel.config(text=fileBase)


tk = Tk()

fileLabel = ttk.Label(text = "No File Selected").pack()

ttk.Button(text = "Select FASTA/Genbank",command = lambda: select_file(fileLabel)).pack()

tk.mainloop()
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: The error is on the line

```
fileLabel.config(text=fileBase)
```

Comment: On which line are you getting the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
fileLabel = ttk.Label(text = "No File Selected")
fileLabel.pack()
```